# Analog of onmouseout for touch devices

Tags: javascript, html, touch, dom-events, touch-event

> Analog of onmousedown is ontouchstart
>
> Analog of onmousemove - ontouchmove
>
> onmouseup - ontouchend
>
> onmouseout - ?

**UPDATE1** I mean that when you touch an element, and without releasing allot finger away from it, is the event that I want to catch

Comment: answer: touchleave.

why is this closed? I call BS on the moderator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the **Update1** I suggest listening to `ontouchend` which will be triggered when the touch will leave the bound object. But still there is no exact analog. Do you have a particular case where you need to know if the touch exited?

Answer (score 0):

There is no touch equivalent for onmouseout.

Answer (score 0):

Both **onMouseOver** and **onMouseOut** are related to hover.  There is no analogy to hover on touch devices so the general answer is to avoid hover.

[Preferred Alternative to OnMouseOver for touch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4550427/prefered-alternative-to-onmouseover-for-touch)