# vue mouseover or hover is not working on ipad

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuejs2

In my application, there are some cards which can be scrollable left to right by using left/right paddles. These paddles are visible when we mouseover on cards.

Now, This is working fine on desktop in all browser(safary,firefox,chrome). Even if i change the responsive design it is working fine.

Problem is visible when we use ipad(ios simulator). Those paddles are visible while hovering over those cards. Paddles are coming if we click on those cards first.

**Div layout**

```
    <div
              v-show="grid"
              class="second-row"
              @mouseover="showPaddle"
              @scroll.passive="setScrolledLeft"
            > .... normal code 
</div>
```

**showPaddle method**

```
showPaddle() {
  const secondRowEl = this.$el.querySelector('.second-row');
  const gridWidth = this.$el.querySelector('.grid').clientWidth;
  const scrollMax = gridWidth - secondRowEl.clientWidth;
  if (gridWidth > secondRowEl.clientWidth) {
    if (secondRowEl.scrollLeft > 0 && secondRowEl.scrollLeft < scrollMax) {
      this.showLeftPaddle = true;
      this.showRightPaddle = true;
    } else if (secondRowEl.scrollLeft >= scrollMax) {
      this.showLeftPaddle = true;
      this.showRightPaddle = false;
    } else if (secondRowEl.scrollLeft <= 0) {
      this.showLeftPaddle = false;
      this.showRightPaddle = true;
    }
  } else {
    this.showLeftPaddle = false;
    this.showRightPaddle = false;
  }
}
```

This code and everything is working fine on all browser in desktop/laptop but not working in ipad(ios simulator).

Please tell me any workaround on this.

Comment: There is no "mouseover" event on touch devices: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4551043/5781499

Comment: Is there any work around on this by using touch events?

Comment: spontaneously I would only think of display the right/left paddles permanent on mobile devices (or touch in general). Quick search how to detect a touch device: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4819886/5781499

Comment: i understood this. Can you help me to rewrite so i can fixed paddles for touch devices and hovering on other devices

Comment: If you post a minimal working example, sure.